# Async Task Updating UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am currently getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{b862cf1} not attached to Activity` error when the following async method updates my home page.

```
new AsyncTask<HomeCardHolder, Void, List<HomeCardModel>>() {
   HomeCardHolder mHomeCardHolder;

   @Override
   protected List<HomeCardModel> doInBackground(HomeCardHolder... params) {
      if (params != null && params.length > 0) {
          mHomeCardHolder = params[0];
      }
      return getPunchCardDeals();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<HomeCardModel> punchCard) {
      if (isActivityAlive() && !ListUtils.isEmpty(punchCard) && mHomeCardHolder != null) {
         mCardAdapter.refreshDataForCards(mHomeCardHolder.getSectionName(), punchCard);
      }
   }

}.execute(homeCardHolder);
```

The thing is `getPunchCardDeals()` retrieves the list of deals but also updates UI elements. I've read that UI elements cannot be updated on a background thread, so what is the proper structure here?

Thanks,
Otterman

---

edit: 
I am checking if the fragment is added.

```
boolean isActivityAlive() {
   return null != getActivity() && isAdded() && !getActivity().isFinishing();

}
```

Comment: only retrieve list/data etc in doInBackground and do your all UI related work in postExecute.

Comment: Please give a complete code example. You should include the class and method which encloses the lines of code shown here. Also show where you create a HomeFragment.

Comment: doInbackground should do the retrieval and process, onPostExecute should do the display.  If you have a UI where you periodically display (say you fetch 100 items, display, then fetch the next 100) you can use publishProgress and update the UI in the progress update.  Just be aware that it will be acting in parallel to doInBackground, so don't update any data structures out from under it without proper locking.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure fragment is added with the activity when you are updating view. For this you should use [fragment.isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()).
So replacing

```
if (isActivityAlive() && !ListUtils.isEmpty(punchCard) && mHomeCardHolder != null)
```

with

```
if (isAdded()&&isActivityAlive() && !ListUtils.isEmpty(punchCard) && mHomeCardHolder != null)
```

may help you.